# Is it required to implement sign in with Apple if there is only phone number for login or sign up?

Tags: ios

Previously, we implement facebook login to enter our app. But we to also implement Sign in with Apple.

We want to simplify our user journey, so we plan to change our sign in policy by using phone number only. Are we also required to implement sign in with Apple in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not required to offer "sign in with apple" in that case:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple

> Apps that use a third-party or social login service (such as Facebook Login, Google Sign-In, Sign in with Twitter, Sign In with LinkedIn, Login with Amazon, or WeChat Login) to set up or authenticate the user’s primary account with the app must also offer Sign in with Apple as an equivalent option. A user’s primary account is the account they establish with your app for the purposes of identifying themselves, signing in, and accessing your features and associated services.
>
> Sign in with Apple is not required if:
>
> - Your app exclusively uses your company’s own account setup and sign-in systems.
>   [...]

Comment: Actually, we are not sure if phone number is a third-party. And what does Apple mean with third-party.